# AngularJS: Reset tab content while creating new tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJS here.

I have a button clicking on which prompts to enter a Tab name and creates a new tab. You can create as many tabs and delete tab as well. In the TAB content I have a table, whose columns are dynamically created. The columns are created by clicking on the Add Column button on the table. Again I could have many columns here. All the above works and can be seen in the JSFiddle as below:

http://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/pactnrb0/1/

What I am looking for is:

1.) When you create a new tab all the content in that Table should be empty. Currently what I have is, if I create a new tab I can see the same content across all tabs or if I move from that to other tab or if I create a new tab.

2.) If I fill up some data in my table and click on Add Tab or try to move to other tab there should be a warning stating to save my changes.

Below is a little sample from the jsfiddle code:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default data-table">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="selectTab($index)" ng-class="{'active':selectedTab == $index}">
          <a data-target="#tab" aria-controls="home" data-toggle="tab">{{tab.id}} <span ng-click="deleteTab($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li ng-click="addTab()">
          <a aria-controls="home" data-toggle="tab">(+) Add Tab</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 <div class="panel-body table-set-columns">
     //Table data
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few changes are required:

Conceptually:

- Do not show initially a table (until the user has added a tab).
- When the new changes are done, you don't need the warning message because the data will be independent in each table, so they will be (temporarily) saved (in client-side app)

Code:

- In the HTML we need to show the table if there is one selected. For this we use the `ng-if` like this: `<table class="table table-bordered" ng-if="targetTable">`. <sup>**edited**</sup>
- We will need two vars: `tableCounter` (for counting how many tables there are currently) and `currentTableId` ( for getting a new table id every time a new one is created.
- We will need a new function called `createTable` which will return a new table object.
- In the `addTab` function we now will do also `$scope.tables.push(createTable());` for creating a new table and `$scope.targetTable = $scope.tables[tableCounter - 1];` for selecting the new table created as the current being shown (as it was done with the just created tab)
- In the `addColumn` and `addNewRow` we check first if there is at least one table (which means there is one table selected) with `if (tableCounter) {...}` <sup>**edited**</sup>
- On the `deleteTab` function now we need to do `$scope.tables.splice(index, 1);` too in order to remove the table corresponding to the deleted tab and `$scope.targetTable = $scope.tables[0];` in order to set the selected table the 1st by default (only if there is at least one table). <sup>**edited**</sup>
- In the `selectTab` function we need to do now `$scope.targetTable = $scope.tables[index];` as well in order to select the table corresponding to the selected tab.(only if there is at least one table). <sup>**edited**</sup>

See **[Working JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lealceldeiro/pactnrb0/34/)** (forked from Yours)

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. The code you shared works mostly as expected but there are 2 issues here. I wont need to define a default tab. The user clicks add tab thats when the first tab is created. Secondly it throws this error in console "angular.js:11358 TypeError: Cannot read property 'columns' of undefined" when you follow this step. You create new tabs, and then delete them and then add new tab again, now when you click on add columns it throws above error. I believe the above error is on line "  var columns = $scope.targetTable.columns, id = columns.length;"

Comment: @kaka1234 I'll take a look into the error now. Just to know... if there is no default tab, the first(default) table does not belong to any tab? When the first tab is created (by the user, no default one) a new table is created and the default table remains without tab? if so, how do you navigate to that table again? ... or when the user creates a new tab you should we associate the default table to that first tab. Could you explain how would be this complete flow?

Comment: The reason I dont want the default tab is that I want the user to give the name to the tab, thats why the pop up for default name. So the flow should be like this. Initially the table is hidden and only the add tab button/link is available (I can take care of visibility). When we click add tab it prompts for tab name and this is when the first table (default) is created. Subsequent adding tabs will create a new copy of table. Deleting tab would delete table associated with tab. Also FYI the error comes when you delete all tabs first and then add new tab, and add column.

Comment: @kaka1234, so initially, there would not be a table being shown... until the user click add tab. Is that right?

Comment: Thats correct, they would only see the "add tab", upon clicking on which a new tab is created and new table is added.

Comment: @kaka1234 I just updated the answer and the **jsfiddle**. Check them out and let me know how it goes (the jsfiddle link changed).

Comment: Works fine. Thanks for your time.

Comment: lealceldeiro, sorry to bother you again. One quick question. The first column "ID" is a static column whose value is auto incremented on each row addition. What if I want to remove the auto increment and let the user add that data. Which update do I need to make.

Comment: Well, @kaka1234, firstly, bear in mind that this new behavior could cause two ID to collide (evaluate that) when they are suppose to be unique (?). That said you just have to comment out this line: `row.id = $scope.targetTable.uniqueIdCounter++;` inside the `addNewRow` function. This will leave the `id` cell blank. You might have to _force_ the user in some way to fill this column, now that there is no default value for it. See this http://jsfiddle.net/lealceldeiro/tr6p1257/2/

Comment: I also tried to comment out the said line above but the issue is even if you fill out that ID column data and move to a different tab, the previous tab value for ID becomes blank, Is this what are you talking about?

Comment: @kaka1234, yes I just noticed it too. Remove this `{{r.id}}` from `<td class="fixed-width" contenteditable="true"></td>` and instead replace it for `<td class="fixed-width" contenteditable="true" ng-model="r[column.id]"></td>` (this might require some additional tweaks). See [jsfiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/lealceldeiro/tr6p1257/6/)

Comment: Got it. Now I think about it, I would be asking the user to save the current table before moving to next tab. So if the save current tab, create new tab and move back then I would just need to populate table with existing values from DB so above scenario may not arise. Thanks for your help though. I would post separate ques if required further on this.